# navController.topViewController or navController.viewControllers.first?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am trying to do a segue from a VC to one that is embedded in a nav controller.

For my purposes, both these lines of code seemingly accomplish the same thing, but was wondering what the real difference between them was and whether one was advantageous to another.

for this...

```
if let navController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
```

is this:

```
    let viewController = navController.viewControllers.first as? myViewController
```

or this:

```
    let viewController = navController.topViewController as? myViewController
```

better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean.

- The `first` view controller is the *first* child view controller of the navigation controller.
- The `topViewController` is the *last* child view controller of the navigation controller.

So they are opposites. It *happens* that on this occasion they are the same view controller because the navigation controller has only one child view controller. But I wouldn't get into the habit, if I were you, of imagining that those two lines say the same thing. They don't.

(Personally, I don't say either of those things. I say `navController.viewControllers[0]`. And I say `as!`, because I'd darned well better be right about the class of that view controller or I want to crash.)

Answer (score 2):

As matt mentioned in the comments, “.first” and “topViewControllers” are the opposite.

“.first” is the first VC (index 0) in the viewControllers array, and “.topViewController” is the last (index n-1).

If you have only one VC inside the navigation controller they will be the same, but if you have more than one, they will mean different VCs.

The better option will depend on which VC you want to segue to. However, I believe the most common one is “.topViewController” because it will segue to the most recently loaded VC or to the first if none were loaded yet.